# Expo-dev-client EAS build on ios simulator crashes instantly when opened

Tags: expo, crash, ios-simulator, eas, expo-dev-client

I am building an expo app and I trying to use expo-dev-client with eas build. When I open the app using eas build on the ios simulator the app crashes instantly after the project is opened. I have attached the error log by apple, the eas.json and my dependancies.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: EA27B8E3-458F-4B45-A90E-D74F34F761D0
CrashReporter Key:   EA2196FB-0472-2775-2FE6-6A6F48C15F3F
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro16,3
Process:             globalPuzzle [54390]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96E7EA7F-1EC1-4ADE-B9D4-E6DFA6236892/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C64DD523-AB75-4717-9610-9D5AFEB95C64/globalPuzzle.app/globalPuzzle
Identifier:          com.itayglobal.globalPuzzle
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [53340]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.96E7EA7F-1EC1-4ADE-B9D4-E6DFA6236892 [41593]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [928]

Date/Time:           2023-05-18 18:55:31.0851 -0500
Launch Time:         2023-05-18 18:55:23.4758 -0500
OS Version:          macOS 13.3.1 (22E772610a)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80045477b __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80004db73 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x7ff800b42f64 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
3   globalPuzzle                           0x10906aa97 -[RNHomeIndicator getHomeIndicatorViewController] + 311
4   globalPuzzle                           0x10906a908 -[RNHomeIndicator setPrefersAutoHidden:] + 40
5   globalPuzzle                           0x10906a883 -[RNHomeIndicator init] + 35
6   globalPuzzle                           0x108afe274 __115-[RCTModuleData initWithModuleClass:bridge:moduleRegistry:viewRegistry_DEPRECATED:bundleManager:callableJSModules:]_block_invoke + 36
7   globalPuzzle                           0x108afef11 -[RCTModuleData setUpInstanceAndBridge:] + 1553
8   globalPuzzle                           0x108b0156a __25-[RCTModuleData instance]_block_invoke + 42
9   globalPuzzle                           0x108b77298 RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync + 56
10  globalPuzzle                           0x108b010e2 -[RCTModuleData instance] + 962
11  globalPuzzle                           0x108a9cf58 __49-[RCTCxxBridge _prepareModulesWithDispatchGroup:]_block_invoke + 184
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013be40 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013d0d9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014cc32 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1502
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014c646 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
16  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003b26cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
17  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003acfbe __CFRunLoopRun + 2429
18  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003ac264 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
19  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff809b4024e GSEventRunModal + 139
20  UIKitCore                              0x1197b57bf -[UIApplication _run] + 994
21  UIKitCore                              0x1197ba5de UIApplicationMain + 123
22  globalPuzzle                           0x1087c5ad0 main + 96
23  dyld_sim                               0x10b682384 start_sim + 10
24  dyld                                   0x11247f41f start + 1903

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8376f41f2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff83774cee6 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff800131e58 abort + 130
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80025a5f2 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80024c7cb demangling_terminate_handler() + 267
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff800032182 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff800259a4b std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 6
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff800259a06 std::terminate() + 54
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013d0ed _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014cc32 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1502
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014c646 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
11  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003b26cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
12  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003acfbe __CFRunLoopRun + 2429
13  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003ac264 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
14  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff809b4024e GSEventRunModal + 139
15  UIKitCore                              0x1197b57bf -[UIApplication _run] + 994
16  UIKitCore                              0x1197ba5de UIApplicationMain + 123
17  globalPuzzle                           0x1087c5ad0 main + 96
18  dyld_sim                               0x10b682384 start_sim + 10
19  dyld                                   0x11247f41f start + 1903

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff837748bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cfnetwork.ats.metrics
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8376ed5b2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8376fb72d mach_msg2_internal + 78
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8376f45e4 mach_msg_overwrite + 692
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff8376ed89a mach_msg + 19
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800159fbc _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 574
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80015a3be dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 55
6   libxpc.dylib                        0x7ff800084e6a xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 219
7   Security                            0x7ff8018ef274 securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 102
8   Security                            0x7ff8018f01f5 securityd_send_sync_and_do + 68
9   Security                            0x7ff8019cf339 SecTrustReportNetworkingAnalytics + 480
10  CFNetwork                           0x7ff80426e9b8 0x7ff8040f8000 + 1534392
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013be40 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013d0d9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800144b23 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1008
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800145826 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 455
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800152475 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 873
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff837749c55 _pthread_wqthread + 327
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff837748bbf start_wqthread + 15
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.1.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

dependancies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "emoji-utils": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "~48.0.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "immer": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-home-indicator": "^0.2.10",
    "react-native-round-flags": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.6.0"
  },
```

Using eas-build and dev-client this way is very crucial for my app so please how can I solve this issue and use eas-build and expo-dev-client on my simulator without it crashing?

*also: if it crashes on the simulator does it mean it will also crash on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Run from Release to Debug mode in simulation in Xcode.
Go Product->Scheme-Edit Scheme then change Run to Debug mode.
I have exactly same crash report you have.
But mine works in Debug mode, but does not work in Release mode.
My problem is it crashes when you go to the next page. Basically in React Navigation.